# Group log data based on threads

Tags: python, java, pandas, log4j, data-processing

I am building a application, in which I will read multiple logs and analyse the process and calls which are taking more time.
It is a multithreaded application, so the logs are not in order as shown below

```
2023.03.24 04:47:14,334 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-13 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/20114
2023.03.24 04:47:14,338 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-10 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,338 [ERROR  ]  pool-499263-thread-10 SomeServiceAdapter: Error no result obtained 20897
2023.03.24 04:47:14,357 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-12 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/20806
2023.03.24 04:47:14,359 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-11 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,377 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-14 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/20115
2023.03.24 04:47:14,382 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-13 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,398 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-15 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/20116
2023.03.24 04:47:14,406 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-12 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,419 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-16 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/12064
2023.03.24 04:47:14,426 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-14 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,426 [ERROR  ]  pool-499263-thread-14 SomeServiceAdapter: Error no result obtained 20115
2023.03.24 04:47:14,442 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-17 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/20110
2023.03.24 04:47:14,447 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-15 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,463 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-18 GetRequestHandler: Sending GET request to SomeService http://{ request - url }/20111
2023.03.24 04:47:14,468 [INFO   ]  pool-499263-thread-16 GetRequestHandler: Response received from SomeService.
2023.03.24 04:47:14,468 [ERROR  ]  pool-499263-thread-16 SomeServiceAdapter: Error no result obtained for 12064
```

As you can see the GET request to the service was executed by thread 13 and response for same request was received after 4-5 lines. I exported all the logs in pandas dataframe, and will use time of the logs to calculate the time taken by particular call. For that I need to group the logs of same call together and then subtract the times to calculate the difference.

I can't think of any way to group the logs of same call together.

The snippet given below is how I want my logs to be shown. I want the threads in ascending order grouped by their own ID. The number following http:{...}/ is the ID of that process.

```
thread-1 Sending GET request to SomeService http:{.....}/12424 
thread-1 Response received from SomeService.
thread-2 Sending GET request to SomeService http:{....}/12344
thread-2 Error no result found 12344
```

There is no ID provided whenever a response is received successfully whereas an ID is provided for errors.